# Should everything be written in sitemap.xml for a dynamic news site?

Tags: xml, web, seo, sitemap

I have a news web site that there are almost 200 000 news in db. I splitted them to sub xml files which contains 1000 links per file.

my sitemapxml looks like :

```
<sitemap>
<loc>http://example.com/sitemap_categories.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2014-11-10T16:01:08+02:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>

<sitemap>
<loc>http://example.com/sitemap_news_200.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2014-12-10T16:01:08+02:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>

<sitemap>
<loc>http://example.com/sitemap_news_199.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2014-12-10T16:01:08+02:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>

<sitemap>
<loc>http://example.com/sitemap_news_198.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2014-12-10T16:01:08+02:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>

...
```

It goes until sitemap_news_0.

Is it a right approach ? Should I put everything to sitemap.xml as I wrote above or index only todays or months news ?

Answer (score 1):

---

easiest solution is to implement proper XML sitemap creator like this here:

https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/standalone-google-sitemap-generator.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your goals and type of content. Usually, news content is important for a specific timeframe while ever-green content may be popular for a long time. However, providing an archive of popular outdated news may drive traffic to your pages. In this way, it totally depends on your goals.

All in all, sitemaps should provide an index for all of the pages except those you intentionally don’t want to be indexed by SEs.